# How to choose degree for polynomial regression?

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I know how to perform polynomial regression. But is there any method to use for estimating the degree of the polynomial that is best suited? Some kind of meta-regression.

With best suited I mean the grade that has the highest probability of being the true degree of the source for the data.

For example, if we look at this picture we can easily "see" that a polynomial of degree 4 would fit nicely:

[image]

A more generalized question is if there is any method to determine if the source is polynomial at all or if it is exponential or something else.

Comment: @saulspatz Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "model selection." In general there are various approaches to decide which model (in this case, which degree) is better, such as AIC, BIC, or cross validation.

Comment: I think cross-validation is a popular technique for this.

Comment: Polynomial regression is only really of use for interpolation, and can be disastrous for extrapolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIC or BIC is the right path to go. These criteria helps you to determine the model that best approximates the generating mechanism. Another, more basic approach is Ramsey RESET test for model misspecification. For example, see here http://lipas.uwasa.fi/~sjp/Teaching/ecm/lectures/ecmc8.pdf

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to
polynomial regression
is to a fit with
Chebychev polynomials,
which essentially is a
least squares fit.

Usually the coefficients
will decrease from the
low order terms,
and you can stop when
the coefficients
get small enough.

You can then convert from
Chebychev form to
polynomial form.

Hope this is
hand-wavey enough.